# How to send an image to the back (layer) using Applescript in Keynote?

Tags: macos, applescript, keynote

I'm inserting a new image into an existing Keynote document. When the image is inserted, it is on the front layer covering some other objects. I would like to send it to the back layer. Is there a built-in Applescript command to do that?

```
tell application "Keynote"
    activate
    tell (open result_keynote)
        tell third slide
            tell (make new image with properties {file:screenshot_file})
                set height to screenshot_height
                set width to screenshot_width
                set position to screenshot_position
                -- set layer position here
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Send to Back is Cmd/Shift/B, no script necessary.

Comment: This is just a small part of an automation effort. I need to do this from script.

Comment: You're overthinking it - `tell application "System Events" to keystroke "b" using {shift down, command down}`

Comment: Yeah, I considered that as a fallback. I just wondered if there is any existing action that I might have missed as built-in action is preferable to a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: It's a whole lot of faff to find & click a menu item compared to just sending the key command. Let me drop something in an answer below, which is only to show the complexity...

Comment: Probably I wasn't clear. I'm not talking about menu items and commands there. I was referring to AppleScript commands (and properties) like 'open', 'close', 'delete', 'make' and so on.

Comment: Mentioned in the 'answer' - it's not in the dictionary [which you can open for any app from the Script Editor File menu.]… so it's either the key command or the GUIscript menu item.

Answer (score 0):

Parking this here just as an example of how to test a menu item & toggle its state if appropriate. This is just copy paste from something else I did in another answer here & does not answer this question as asked, though it does cover 'how to click a menu item'.

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "TextEdit"
    set v to (value of attribute "AXMenuItemMarkChar" of menu item "Smart Quotes" of menu 1 of menu item "Substitutions" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Edit" of menu bar 1)

    if v = "✓" then
        click menu item "Smart Quotes" of menu 1 of menu item "Substitutions" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Edit" of menu bar 1
    end if
end tell
```

I don't see anything in the Dictionary for Keynote that specifically deals with layers, or front to back.